# Eventbrite API - how to get list of all user's evnets?

Tags: php, eventbrite

I'm using the code below to get a response from Eventbrite's API, which generates a response

```
$results = file_get_contents('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?token=XXXXXXXXXXXX&user.id=5331000601');
```

The only problem is that I expect this user to have lots of events (I can see that on the Eventbrite website), but the URL above returns nothing for 'events', as per below

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "object_count": 0, 
        "page_number": 1, 
        "page_size": 50, 
        "page_count": 0, 
        "has_more_items": false
    }, 
    "events": []
}
```

What I'd like is to get a list of all the user's Event IDs. What am I doing wrong?

This is the user's Eventbrite page: https://www.eventbrite.com.au/o/makmak-5331000601

Comment: it looks correct to me after reviewing there API the only thing I can see that might cause an issue, is if the events aren't listed as public explicitly. Also try using organizer.id in just for good measure.

Comment: @OrlandoP. Thanks - the organizer.id worked. The results include a series_id of 15241955098. I tried querying the API with this (https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/series/15241955098/?token=XXX) but the results don't seem to contain the dates of the events (no series_dates array), unlike what the API reference doc indicates. Any ideas?